# Prerequisite gets downloaded and installed everytime

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-installer, outlook-addin, winforms-interop

I have created an **Outlook Add In using Visual Studio 2010**. Every time I tried to install the setup **.Net framework prerequisite gets downloaded and installed even if it exists** . How can I **change the settings in the .msi to prevent** this from happening ?

Comment: How are you creating the msi? Visual Studio Installer Project? WiX? Something else?

Comment: VS 2010 includes Windows Installer projects. So, I guess it is a Windows Installer project.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I am using Visual Studio Installer Project. In the prerquisite list, i am selecting the required .net framework version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the .net framework to get your add-in loaded by the host application. Excluding the .net runtime from the list of prerequisites can lead to loading failures. Anyway, for excluding the .net framework you need to unselect a corresponding entry from the list of prerequisites:

[image]